# How to get a variable inside of a script tag from many html files with JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript

I have in a directory multiple files like so:

```
file_1.html
file_2.html
file_3.html
```

Each of this files has a tag script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var target_date = new Date('December 25, 2022 00:00:00').getTime() + (86400000); 
</script>
```

How can I get in javascript the target_date from each of the files.
This is my code:

```
async function loopFiles() {
    const filesNumber = 3;
    for (step = 0; step < filesNumber; step++){
        console.log(step);
        // How can I get the target_date variable from each file? 
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is client-side: You cannot. If this is server-side: Use the `fs` node module to load the file, use a regular expression to extract the date (in this example, a DOM parser would be overkill and would still need further operations to parse the script contents, so...)

Comment: Please explain a little bit more: where is the function `loopFiles` supposed to work, on the server (e.g., in node) or from another html file (on the same server?), i.e., accessed in browser

Comment: @kikon , the script is supposed to work from the server side. I'll use the date from the target_date to create other functions and calculations.

Comment: Then something on the lines of (condensed) `require('fs').readFileSync(\`file_${step+1}.html\`, {encoding:'utf8'}).match(/var target_date = (new Date[^;]+); /)[1];`, right?

Answer (score -2):

here sire pp head

```
var circle_f3a483b3a7ba46748ac935d3995f4f6b = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var circle_a01d1791063145b18b439bd7687bc97f = {
  foo: "bar"
};
var layer_control_aec3ac6e0e424b74a19b4c9d1c78ffeb = {
  foo: "bar"
};

window.onload = function() {
  for (var name in this) {
    if (name.includes("layer")) {
      console.log(name , "=" , this[name])
      for(let key in this[name]) {
        console.log('key', key, 'value', this[name][key])
        
      }
    }
  }

};
```